# Eating Meat from Siyum

Tags: halacha, nine-days, siyum

The [Rema (551:10)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.551.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

ובסעודת מצוה כגון מילה ופדיון הבן וסיום מסכת וסעודת אירוסין אוכלין בשר ושותין יין כל השייכין לסעודה - At a Mitzvah Meal like a Milah, Pidyon HaBen, a Siyum Masechta, or an Engagement Meal, we eat meat and drink wine, all those who are relevant to the meal...

If the baal simcha sent meat from the siyum to someone's home after the siyum was over (and they themselves did not attend), would that person be allowed to eat the meat from the siyum during the Nine Days?

Answer (score 7):

Nitei Gavriel 40:7 quotes the Divrei Malkiel 3:27 that Baalei Bris (the people directly involved with a Bris) can eat food from a Bris that was sent to their house because it like is their Yom Tov, however, other people cannot. Additionally, he writes, by other Seudos Mitzvah there would be no Heter.

Answer (score -2):

From the Rema you bring it says "ובסעודת מצוה". That means that one is at the meal itself. That's what the Rema means. If someone is elsewhere it's not the seudas mitzvah.

Comment: Maybe "shayach" can be somewhere else if you want to participate and are eating leftovers? I don't understand your proof

Comment: I don't understand your comment. His language is clear that you need to be present at the seudah. Why are you trying to force the translation of ובסעודת מצוה as being at another address?

Comment: He says for a seudat mitzva anyone shayach can eat. Maybe this person is shayach. Indeed, if I threw a large siyum and my chavrusa was unable to attend but i brought some leftover cake to him afterwards, I'd think he's shayach to the seudah.

Comment: Why do you force the translation of "shayach to the seudah" to be "standing in the same place"? Is that what shayach means in any other context?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think he's translating the beis of beseudas mitzvah that anyone physically present at the siyum and is shayach can eat it, and perhaps you're translating the beis of beseudas mitzvah as "regarding" a seudas mitzvah?